# Не работает bot.send_message в библиотеке telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

В отладчике после обработки декоратора просто пропускает функцию `bot_notification(message)`

```
import telebot
TOKEN='token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
k='abcd'
v='22'
balance_in_eth='1.312'
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_notification(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Изменение количества транзакций в адресе {k}. Значение изменилось на {v}.'+"\n"+'Текущий баланс ' + str(balance_in_eth) + ' ETH')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конце вашего кода добавьте строчку

```py
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: А как мне сделать чтобы сообщение приходило сразу, а не после отосланного мною любого сообщения в чат с ботом?

Comment: Вы можете импортировать модуль `time` и поставить конкретное время отправки